# Fishy, Dishy: Adjectives used as nouns?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, suffixes

In the children song below, I'm bit confused on the two lines highlighted:

> Dance to your daddy
> My little baby
> Dance to your daddy
> My little lamb
>
> **You will have a fishy**
> **In your little dishy**
> You will have a fishy
> when the boat comes in.

I get the meaning, but I wonder: how come the adjectives fishy and dishy are being used as nouns here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's true that there's a suffix spelled `-y` which forms adjectives.  This suffix *looks* the same, but it's actually different.

This is a **hypocoristic** or **diminutive** suffix `-y` which can be used on nouns (including proper nouns).  It does *not* change word class to adjective.  In this case, *fishy* is a noun, and so is *dishy*.

So what's this suffix do, then?  Basically, **it makes stuff sound cuter.**

This suffix turns *dog* into *doggy* and *pig* into *piggy*.  Sometimes the sound of the base word changes slightly, so *cat* becomes *kitty*.  For example, if you decided to have a conversation with a piglet, you might say something like this:

> Who's a cute wittle piggy!?  You are!  That's right, ***yes you are***!

(Note the change from *little* to *wittle*.  This, too, makes stuff sound cuter.)

This suffix is also spelled `-ie` and is often used to form pet names.  (That's what **hypocoristic** means.)  And if you attach it to a multi-syllable word, you usually get rid of every syllable except the first.  For example, you might call someone named Christine *Chrissie*, first shortening the name to *Chris* and then adding the suffix.

None of this is acceptable in formal Standard English, but it's acceptable informally.

Comment: It also makes the lines scan better (three trochees).

Comment: +1. Re: "None of this is acceptable in formal Standard English": the process is not productive in formal Standard English, but some of the words so formed do eventually make their way into the formal language. Two particularly old examples are *baby* and *puppy*; a more recent example is *doggy* or *doggie* in compounds such as *doggy paddle* and *doggie bag*.

Comment: Great answer! And I learned a new word, which happens a lot when I read your answers :)  One tiny thing: I don't think it's the base word changing from *cat* to *kitty*. A baby cat is a *kitten*, and I'm pretty sure *kitty* comes from *kitten*. It just so happens that *kitty* is used to refer to cats of all ages, whereas we have both *dog -> doggy* and *pup -> puppy* for dogs :)

Comment: @WendiKidd Diachronically, this is true, but synchronically, you get *kitty* when you apply `-y` to *cat*.  Try it.  Dog, doggy.  Cat, kitty.  I skipped over the diachronic aspect because I don't think etymology is on-topic on ELL unless it helps you understand something.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I agree with the gist of it. But – just as a personal opinion – once you change _little_ to _wittle_, it's not cuter any more, it's more annoying. (Can you guess that Elmo is my least favorite muppet?) +1 for a great answer, though.